# Error “collect2.exe: Id returned 1 exit status” with Qt 5.2.1

Tags: c, windows, qt

When I try to build my app I get the following error. Any idea?
I use Qt 5.2.1 on Win8 with MinGW 4.8 32 bit

```
16:14:47: Running steps for project test2...
16:14:47: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
16:14:47: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/ha/Desktop/build-test2-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\test2.exe debug/main.o  
debug/main.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Debug:77: recipe for target 'debug\test2.exe' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\test2.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/ha/Desktop/build-test2-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
16:14:48: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test2 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.1 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
16:14:48: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
debug/main.o: file not recognized: File truncated
```

Tells you the file `main.o` was not created correctly. Either select "rebuild" from the menu, or delete that file and "build" again.

This usually happens when you interrupt the compiler while it's outputting the object file.

Comment: This also means that most likely the compiler in question does not output the object file atomically :(

Comment: @Kuba how do you imagine atomically writing a file would work? That's impossible in the usual sense of the word.

Comment: `QSaveFile` does it, and tools that aren't broken do it, too. You write to a temporary file, close it, then rename it over the output file. As long as the computer and the OS itself is kept running, you can kill the process at any time and you won't ever have a partially written output file. Partial temp files are of no consequence. If the rename-over-file is a single operation, then you will also never get the existing file destroyed without something complete to replace it. It's really simple.